# How do I login to a preinstalled Ubuntu file system archive?

Tags: ubuntu, login, root, sd-card, user

I installed a preinstalled ubuntu 12.04 desktop root fs archive on SD card and booting it on my new Chrome book.
I was able to boot and see the Ubuntu Login screen and able to login as guest. But how can I login as a real user on that system? Or how do I create one if there isn't any user yet?

The ubuntu desktop root fs I used was 
ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+ac100.tar.gz 
from this site: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/

Comment: Does this help? http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-createdisable-and-delete-new-user-account-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot.html

Comment: by the way the default root password is no password (blank) so thats how you get root access for new ubuntu linux installation. When you try an operation requiring su privilege you should be prompted to enter a password - that will become your new root password. For instance see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-root-password-default-password/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But blank password didn't work for me. Basically after booting from my chromebook by pressing CTRL+u (booting from usb) I can see the standard Ubuntu login screen. And I can only login to it as Guest. When I'm logged in to Ubuntu desktop as guest the first thing i do is click on Wifi icon and try selecting my wifi network, there it ask for root authentication, and i just click Ok without any password, it didnt' like it.

Comment: try it on terminal like this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: rather than leave it blank I think you have to put something of your choice in password field and it becomes the new password (so make sure you note what you type in the field). Try that in the wifi dialog. If doesn't work, also try it the terminal way too http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Thanks so much. You answer gave me a clue. I basically login to the actual chrome os in developer mode and drop into shell then mount my sd card and then chroot to that cart file system and do useradd as you suggested. Thanks again.

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what sajawikio suggested, I basically logged in to the actual chrome os in developer mode (instructions are here http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-series-5-chromebook) 
and drop into shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>) where<kbd>→</kbd> is the forward arrow key on chromebook keyboard where normally F2 is located on regular keyboards.
Then mount sd card

`$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk1p3 /mnt`

and then chroot to that cart file system

`$ sudo chroot /mnt`

and do useradd as described in link sajawikio sugusted: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/add-a-user-on-ubuntu-server/

Then exit and reboot.